# StreamPlayer "after" function isn't being called

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am creating a discord bot that can play music but I'm a bit stuck because when
the bot finishes playing music is should leave the current voice channel. However this isn't happening, instead my `after` function `vc.disconnect` isn't being called at all though I've followed the instructions on the [FAQ page.](http://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#why-is-my-after-function-being-called-right-away)

```
vc = await bot.join_voice_channel(ctx.message.author.voice_channel)
player = await vc.create_ytdl_player(arg.split(' ')[1], after=vc.disconnect)
player.start()
```

Comment: If I change the function to `after=lambda: print("exit")` the output comes after the ytfl window closes.

Comment: What happens if you do the same thing: `after=lambda: vc.disconnect()`?

Comment: Apparently also nothing.

Comment: Then that would mean it *is* called but does not do what you expect. Make a three-liner function that prints something, calls `vc.disconnect()` and then prints another thing and put that as `after`. What happens?

Comment: In the docs, it says that "All exceptions the finalizer throws are silently discarded." could this mean that is there is an error no error message is being outputted.

Comment: Yes, that would be so. I'm looking at the source code to `.disconnect()` ([here](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/115c22633c8181cf7e1be965c122366387d013f3/discord/voice_client.py#L284)) and it seems to exit early `if not self._connected.is_set()`. Maybe that's the key? Add a fourth line to the little test function that prints `vc._connected.is_set()`.

Comment: @Tomalak ok i'll try it

Comment: I added that and now the output from the function is `end 1` then `end 2` then `True`

Comment: Don't know if this helps but the output from `print(vc.disconnect()) ` is `<generator object VoiceClient.disconnect at 0x05A71ED0>`

Comment: I think I found the reason. The docs say that you cannot run a coroutine in the `after` callback, because this is not thread-safe. But `vc.disconnect()` is a coroutine. See the answer - I was just about to write the same thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `vc.disconnect` is a coroutine. You need to handle it differently, as the `after` call doesn't await the coroutine since the voice player is just a `Thread`.

According to the [docs](http://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#how-do-i-pass-a-coroutine-to-the-player-s-after-function), this is how it should be handled:

```
def my_after():
    coro = vc.disconnect()
    fut = asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(coro, client.loop)
    try:
        fut.result()
    except:
        pass

player = await voice.create_ytdl_player(url, after=my_after)
player.start()
```

---

Also as noted by the [docs](http://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#how-do-i-pass-a-coroutine-to-the-player-s-after-function), the following warning:

> **Warning**
>
> This function is only part of 3.5.1+ and 3.4.4+. If you are not using
>   these Python versions then use
>   `discord.compat.`.

Meaning that if you're running Python 3.4.0-3.4.3 or 3.5.0, your `my_after` needs to be changed to this:

```
def my_after():
    from discord.compat import run_coroutine_threadsafe
    coro = vc.disconnect()
    fut = run_coroutine_threadsafe(coro, client.loop)
    try:
        fut.result()
    except:
        pass
```

Comment: Ok, so this was something new. My python script contained a `#try:` which made the editor indent the code that came after it even though `try:` was never ran. This lead to some kind of error that wasn't outputted some where and some how, after removing the `#try:`s and re indenting every line the code ran seamlessly. The more you know.